# .htaccess -- css is deactivated

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

After I edited my .htaccess. the css file cannot be reached anymore. How can get rid of this problem.

If I disable my rewrite rules, yes then it works fine, but when I type file.php?id=5&title=hello in the url bar, it doesn't redirect me to file.php?id/title, so I have to type it manually, when I do then css is removed

**.htaccess Code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ file.php?id=$1&title=$2
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ file.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

I also tried this:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ file.php?id=$1&title=$2
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ file.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

I also tried this:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond $1 !^(jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|png|media|txt|xml|css|js)
 RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ file.php?id=$1&title=$2
 RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ file.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

I want to hide my URL, for improved security against SQL injection.

**UPDATE**

This is a working version:

url: `http://localhost/21760`

**.htaccess file:**

```
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
        RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ file.php?id=$1&
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
        RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ file.php?id=$1
```

I used this and it works like a charm, without the backslash.

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-watch-file-([0-9]+).html file.php?title=$1&id=$2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can put a condition for your rules, so those then wont apply to files which exist

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

You can also add a one for directories

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Then your file may look like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ file.php?id=$1&title=$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ file.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

Comment: I even tried RewriteCond **%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f**

Comment: if I disable my rewrite rules, yes then it works fine, but when I type file.php?id=5&title=hello in the url bar, it doesn't redirect me to file.php?id/title, so I have to type it manually, when I do then css is removed

Comment: What URL does it show for your css when rules are active? is that correct?

Comment: I'm using xampp packet, maybe it's relevant

Comment: <link type="text/css" href="./css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: when I type this in url bar, then css is active: http://localhost/file.php?id=21760&title=Sinister

Comment: updated my post with a working version...but without title, so it's hard for search engines to find the site

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions as posted are the correct way to prevent existing files from being rewritten by mod_rewrite.
If you're able to: check your apache access and / or error logs to see what happens exactly when you make a call to your CSS URI directly in your browser, and let us know what that results in.

Second thought: is the problem that you cannot access your CSS URI? Or is the problem that your CSS doesn't appear to be working when calling a webpage?
If the latter is the case, then you could also be dealing with a relative vs absolute URI problem when calling your CSS file, you could try adding the following below the line of "RewriteEngine On":

> RewriteBase /

Comment: updated my post with a working version...but without title, so it's hard for search engines to find the site

Comment: Please note that we can't reach your server by localhost. If you want to make it available online you're going to have to upload it on a public domain that we can access.
Meanwhile: did you get any info from the logs and / or any results from using RewriteBase?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ file.php?id=$1&title=$2
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ file.php?id=$1&title=$2
```